# No page break between a paragraph and a multicol

Tags: page-breaking

I want to prevent a page break between a paragraph and a `multicol` environment that comes right after.
I do not mind a page break inside the paragraph or inside the `multicol`.
I also don't mind if the text doesn't fill the page completely, so I use `\raggedbottom`

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6]

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: What about `\enlargethispage` or the `needspace` package?

Comment: @PeterWilson it seems that I will have to calculate the number of required lines by hand -- is that correct?

Comment: If you decide you need at least the last 2 lines of the paragraph and the first 2 lines of your `multicol` then you need space for 4 (maybe 5) lines. It is up to you how you want things to look.

Comment: Try `\premulticols=0pt`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of your MWE which includes code according to my suggestion and also John Kormylo's suggestion. See which works best for you.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{needspace}  % added per Peter W.

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-6]

%\needspace{5\baselineskip} % added per Peter W.
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.
\premulticols=0pt % added per John Kormylo
\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \item Some dummy text
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

John Kormylo's suggestion seems neater, and more broadly applicable, to me.